# Return value from function (action button)

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction

Does anyone know how can I get o return a value from this function?
I want to return t , the value is a image
Pd. I want to return the value in this viewcontroller

```
@IBAction func firmaButton(_ sender: Any)  {
  let storyBoard1 : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NuevaCuenta", bundle: nil)
  let ViewControllerDos1 = storyBoard1.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NCFirma") as! NCFirma
  ViewControllerDos1.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

    ViewControllerDos1.clickedCallback = { t   in
        self.firmaButton.setImage(t, for: .normal)
        self.firmaButton.transform = self.firmaButton.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        self.firmaButton.frame =  CGRect(x: 13, y: 8, width: 294, height: 112)
        self.firmaButton.clipsToBounds = true
        RegTempNuevaCuenta.imgFirma = t
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.myOrientation = .portrait

    }

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerDos1, animated: true)



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@IBAction` function is system based functions based on user interaction. They don't return anything and the return type is Void for this type function

Comment: so, there is no way to get the value `t` or send tha value to one var ? :c

Comment: help @Mac3n xd please

Comment: you can define a variable outside of your function and assign `t` to that, and do what you want in variable didSet. example:  var someValue: Int = 0 {
   didSet{
      // when you assign the `t` to `someValue` , this block of code executes
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

While you can't technically "return" from this function, there are certainly other paradigms within Swift that are made for this.

If you're trying to pass values between controllers, check out [this guide](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) to Protocols and Delegates.